# Regarding memory consumption in Kafka

Tags: memory, kubernetes, apache-kafka

We are having a query regarding memory consumption on kafka scale out. It would be very helpful if you can give suggestion/solution for the below query.
We are running kafka as docker container on kubernetes.

Memory limit of 4GiB is configured for Kafka broker POD. With some large load Kafka broker POD’s memory reached 4GiB. So we decided to manually scale out Kafka broker POD replicas from 1 to 3. But after scale out, for same load each Kafka broker PODs are consuming 4GiB memory.  We expected Kafka broker POD’s memory consumption to ~1.33GiB as we are running 3 PODs for same amount of load.

Before Kafka Broker Scale out :
1 broker 
6 topics each with 1 partition each
Memory consumption: 4GiB

After Kafka Broker Scale out and rebalancing topics over all the brokers:
3 broker 
6 topics each with 1 partitions each 
Memory consumption: 10GiB (Pod1: 2GiB, Pod2: 4GiB, Pod3: 4GiB)

After Kafka Broker Scale out and rebalancing topics over all the brokers:
3 broker 
6 topics each with 3 partitions each 
Memory consumption: 12GiB (Pod1: 4GiB, Pod2: 4GiB, Pod3: 4GiB)

All deployments are tested with same amount of load. Replication factor for all topics is 1.

**Edit 1**

[image: Kafka Broker POD's Memory Utilization]

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage? Can you show JVM usage graphs instead of just single numbers? What are you even setting for the heap size of Kafka processes?

Comment: Can we see your Kafka `DockerFile`?

Comment: We are using Prometheus to measure Kafka broker memory. 
Following is Java heap option set in Kafka's config map.
kafka.heap.opts: -Xmx2048m -Xms512m